# Indenting disturbed when adding superscript to rowname of a grouped row using kable in latex

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

How do I add superscript to name of a particular row of a table created using kable in **latex** environment ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322881/how-can-i-subscript-names-in-a-table-from-kable) link gives solution for markdown). I tried following:

```
at2=cbind(1:5,6:10,11:15)
rownames(at2)=c("one", "two", "three", "four$^1$", "five")
kable(at2,format = "latex",booktabs=T)
```

But this isn't working.

> [For image of result click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZPX4.png)

EDIT: 
The first problem is solved with `escape = FALSE` but now a new problem related to indentation has come up. I am using `group_rows` which automatically creates indenting. Using `escape` is creating problem with this indenting. Code:

```
at2=cbind(1:5,6:10,11:15)
rownames(at2)=c("one", "two", "three", "four$^1$", "five")
kable(at2,format = "latex",booktabs=T,escape = FALSE,col.names = month.abb[1:3])%>%
 group_rows("group1",1,2)%>%
 group_rows("group2",3,5)
```

> [New Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZLtb.png)

Comment: Please add a reproducible example.  We don't have `somedata`.

Comment: Use the `escape` argument -- see the help page.

Comment: @user2554330: Thanks! `escape` worked in the sample example but not yet in my main file. So something else is wrong there. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Then you should edit your question to be more like your main file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add superscript `footnote_marker_number` should be handy

```r
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

#sample data
at2 <- cbind(1:5, 6:10, 11:15)
rownames(at2) <- c("one", "two", "three", paste0("four", footnote_marker_number(1, "latex")), "five")

kable(at2, format = "latex", escape = F, col.names = month.abb[1:3]) %>%
  group_rows("group1", 1, 2) %>%
  group_rows("group2", 3, 5)
```

**Output is:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not usually use `kable`, but I found a solution to your problem with the `xtable` package.

```
library(xtable)
print(xtable(at2, auto = T), type='latex', sanitize.text.function=identity,
 comment=FALSE, include.colnames = F,hline.after = c(0,nrow(at2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But since I am making a more complex table I want to stick to kable(). I have edited the question as the initial problem is solved but now I am facing some other issue.